# How to exchange symbol current

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

How to change format currency '.' to ',' in asp.net MVC4
ex: 10,000 thay cho 10.000
i have file template @Model.ToString("n0")

Comment: Did you set the correct CultureInfo?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ToString() overload that allows the culture to be specified.

```
// Use the culture you desire instead of en-US
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US"); 
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString(specifier, culture));
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d8ztz0sa.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencygroupseparator.aspx

You can modify the sample code and output by specifying the number format and `CurrencyGroupSeparator`

```
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class NumberFormatInfoSample {

   public static void Main() {

      // Gets a NumberFormatInfo associated with the en-US culture.
      NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo( "en-US", false ).NumberFormat;

      // Displays a value with the default separator (",").
      Int64 myInt = 123456789;
      Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N0", nfi ) );

      // Displays the same value with a specified separator.
      nfi.CurrencyGroupSeparator = ".";
      Console.WriteLine( myInt.ToString( "N0", nfi ) );

   }
}


/* 
This code produces the following output.

123,456,789
123.456.789
*/
```